# Is there a way to create a database table when a button is click at the frontend end in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

please is there a way to create a new table in Laravel when a button is clicked at the front end. Something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE MyGuests
(
    id        INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastname  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    email     VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: It is possible, yes, however why would you create TABLES upon `frontend` button click?

Comment: Am creating an Examination system..i want to create exams based on the Name of the course. The user creates new table with the name of the course and add the quizzes to it

Comment: I don't want to create two different table and link them

Comment: So for 200 courses, 200 new tables? I think you are architecturally doing it wrong.

Comment: Okay..then I will create Courses Table and Quizzes table and link them.

Comment: That would be a much better approach.